# Prevent LaTeX from inserting a new line

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim

How do I prevent LaTeX from inserting a new line?

Here's the code:

```
bla bla bla
\begin{verbatim}C:\Program Files\Product Name\Some other extensions\mail box name\end{verbatim}
```

The output is:

> bla bla bla
>    
>   `C:\Program Files\Product Name\Some other extensions\mail box name`

That's my problem: I'm unable to prevent LaTeX from inserting a new line after "bla".

Is my problem somewhat related with the fact that I'm using `verbatim`?

Comment: You might want `\verb|C:\Program Files\Product Name\Some other extensions\mail box name|`

Comment: @cgnieder: Your comment worse an answer!

Comment: I must use verbatin not \verb

Comment: `\verbatim` always starts a new line.

Comment: Is there some command which acts as a countermeasure?

Comment: Why do you _have_ to use `{verbatim}`? It's to be used for displayed verbatim material whereas `\verb` is for inline material.

Comment: As `verbatim` is a list-type environment, there is little one can do about the new line, just like for `itemize` or `enumerate`. May I ask again what's the problem with `\verb`?

Comment: @cgnieder: Write up an answer, so this question can be considered closed.

Comment: @werner: surely there's no point in cgnieder writing up an answer after the requester has said [s]he "must" not use the proposed solution.  (of course, under h{is|er} constraint, there doesn't seem anything one can do, short of rewriting verbatim to do something completely else ... but that's not a solution i would care to propose.)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Your question together with your comment

> I must use `verbatim` not `\verb`

is a bit confusing. You apparently want inline verbatim material yet not want to use the command that produces it. Unless you can explain why `\verb` (or [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings)' `\lstinline` or [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted)'s `\mint` or ...) doesn't work for you you're unlikely to get a better answer than what I already said in the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Some inline verbatim \verb|&%$_^| and some displayed material:
\begin{verbatim}
 &%$_^
\end{verbatim}
Some text after to show the spacing

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you insist in using an environment for inline verbatim material you could use [`fancyvrb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb)'s `BVerbatim` environment which puts its contents in a TeX box. It might still not be what you're looking for when you need more than one line, though:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

Some text before
\begin{BVerbatim}[gobble=1]
 &%$_^ 
\end{BVerbatim}
\ Some text after to show the spacing

\bigskip

text
\begin{BVerbatim}
 two
 lines 
\end{BVerbatim}
\ text

\bigskip

bla bla bla
\begin{BVerbatim}
C:\Program Files\Product Name\Some other extensions\mail box name
\end{BVerbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the last example will cause an overfull `\hbox`.